# Unable to connect MYSQL database from a Java programm in Ubuntu 16.04 (Communications link failure)

Tags: java, mysql

My java program is working fine when I use localhot instead of IP address, but getting error when I connect using IP address. (I have to use IP address to connect, because it is a client server application).

I have also changed this /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file bind address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0, But again I get the error message like -

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.**

My code is:-

```
try{
      Connection con;
      Statement st;
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con=DriverManager.getConnection(
      "jdbc:mysql://172.16.16.185:3306/itcentre?
       verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true","root","");

    st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from teacher");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
    System.out.println(e);
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked that there is connectivity between your computer and the server? Have you tested the connection with a client?

Comment: Have you granted privileges to your client computer?

Comment: Is your server listening on the IP address?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza- Yes connectivity is ok between computers. This program is not working on server PC also, if I use IP address of the system instead of localhost in connection string.

Comment: ,@Scary Wombat-Yes connectivity is ok between computers. This program is not working on server PC also, if I use IP address of the system instead of localhost in connection string.

Comment: @Maurice Perry-Yes connectivity is ok between computers. This program is not working on server PC also, if I use IP address of the system instead of localhost in connection string.

Comment: *if I use IP address of the system instead of localhost in connection string* what do you mean with this? Also, my second question is if you have using a MySQL client from **your** computer to test the connectivity with the MySQL server in the remote server.

Comment: Have you tested connecting using mysql command first? "mysql -h 172.16.16.185 -u root"

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - Dear sir, My means is If I use  
  
 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://172.16.16.185:3306/itcentre?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true","root","");          It gives the above error. and when I use con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itcentre?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true","root","");             It is working fine. Remember that I am running this program on server machine.

Comment: @Santosh- It gives     ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.16.16.185' (111)

Comment: @Santosh It got the mysql terminal, means it was successful

Comment: Forget about using `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` because those mean your own computer, not the server. Now, the issue is that the server is not configured to accept connections from your computer. You need to update the server user settings to accept connections for your pc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes you are right. Now it is solved. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone to help me. After struggling to many other issues, finally I have the luck with this solution. I logged into my mysql database using phpmyadmin and then

User Accounts ---> login information ---> and changed Host name from localhost to any host.

See the screen shot -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Java can definitely establish an SSL connection without a client validating the certificate chain of the server.
The classes that are establishing the connection (javax.net.ssl classes) would normally treat the unverified server certificate with suspicion and would fail the handshake.
But they provide a way for the user's of those classes to in effect say "It's ok if the server's certificate doesn't validate, go ahead and establish the connection".
That is what's happening when you say verifyServerCertificate=false.